# How to retain search string inside items while checking an item in refinementlist of instantsearch react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-instantsearch

> here, an user searched inside items of Refinementlist

[image: here, an user searched inside items of Refinementlist]

> user checked an item of Refinementlist

[image: user checked an item of Refinementlist]

The requirement is to retain the search string after checking any item of the Refinementlist.
the default feature of the Refinementlist with search inside items to clear the searched string from the search box while checking any item there in algolia instantsearch react-js.

How to not clear the search string while checking any item of the Refinementlist until and unless user clears it manually in algolia instantsearch react-js?
I am using this piece of code of react-instantsearch-dom package

```
  <RefinementList
      attribute={string}
      // Optional parameters           
      limit={number}
      showMore={true}
      showMoreLimit={number}
      searchable={true}
      transformItems={(items) =>
                        orderBy(items, "label",asc)
                      }
    />
```